# Magento getProductCollection not working.

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

Here is my Magento code to get all new products but it has suddenly stopped working. I added some new categories and then when I saw frontend New Arrivals section was empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="new-products">

<div class="title_index">

<!-- <div class="pagination_carousel" id="foo3_pag"></div>-->
 <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Arrivals') ?></h2>
</div>

<div class="index_cont">

<div class="list_carousel">         

<ul id="user_interaction">

<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>

<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>        

<li><h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220, 200) ?>" width="150" height="130" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>

<div class="descr"><?php echo($_product->getSku()); ?></div>

<div class="new_price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?></div>

<div class="new_pr_btn"><input value="1" type="text" name="qty" class="my-qty-box" /><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php 
echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></div>

                        </li>        

    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </ul>

                <div class="clear"></div>           

                </div>

</div>

<div class="shadow-div"></div>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks
Dani

Comment: Could you possibly attach the code for the block?

Comment: Did you reindex/refresh cache? What's the dump of $this->getProductCollection()? Can you execute the MySQL-Statement of the collection fetched in the Block-file in the database directly?

Answer (score 0):

$sql=$this->getProductCollection()->getSelect();  place this code at top of your phtml.
echo $sql;
This will show you sql qquery.

Now fire this query directly in phpMyAdmin or miniadmin and check whether you have records for this query or not.

If not diagnose this sql query, think of filters that resulted in some conditions this will lead you to a fix.

Else you paste sql query here for further comments.

Note : if flat catalog is on code will check flat catalog table.So check if these tables do have all products opulated.If not run indexing.